# PHP, Wordpress - Function and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Ok so I'm trying to create a function to find and replace certain words(phrases) within the posts of wordpress. I'm using a mySQL database to store the required data (search and find).
then replace them with an associated word(phrase) also from the database.

Their are more than one associated words(phrases) so it has to randomly pick one from the table in the database. I'm not to sure how much of this could be done through mySQL?..

The other Thing is that only 4 words(phrases) should be replaced. (At random so it could be anywhere in the post).

I ended up with the process getting stuck in a loop, look I may have gone about this the wrong way. Some guidance would be great.

Comment: Please, at least, explain what is going wrong. What do you see? What is not working properly? You have to give more info if you want help.

Comment: Yer sorry, so I can get the words(phrases) that need to be replaced to be replaced but they all get replaced with the same associated word(phrase) from the database, so each word(phrase) needs to be replaced but not always the same their maybe on occasion the same.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your `$KeywordRowsArray` is empty when you use it inside you try-catch block because of a syntax error in the SQL string that queries the db to populate it :

```
  SELECT DISTINCT KeywordPhrase FROM SearchArticalesWith
```

Should it not be `SearchArticlesWith` and not `SearchArticalesWith`?...

Comment: That isn't causing the issue, as I miss spelled it in the database as well haha.